# Average Sampling Number for Double Sampling Plan with Curtailment

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the average sampling number for a double sampling plan with curtailment. I'm very new to looping within R so I am looking for some help. I come from an engineering background without much proper programming training so they are difficult for me. The plot that I'm trying to create compares the ASN with and without curtailment.

I've tried to put the for loop in different spots without much luck.

```
asnWOcurt <- n4_1 + n4_2*(pbinom(c4_2,n4_1,p_vec) - 
pbinom(c4_1,n4_1,p_vec))
summ_m <- 0
summ_i <- 0

for (i in (c4_1+1):c4_2) {
  for (m in (c4_2-i+1):n4_2) {
    summ_m <- summ_m + m*pnbinom(c4_2-i+1,m,p_vec)
  }
  summ_i <- summ_i + (n4_2*dbinom(c4_2-i, n4_2, p_vec) + 
summ_m)*pbinom(i,n4_1,p_vec)
}
asnWcurt <- n4_1 + summ_i 

 plot(p_vec, asnWOcurt, type="o", col="blue", pch="o", lty=1, 
xlim=c(0,0.2), ylim=c(80,200) )
  points(p_vec, asnWcurt, col="red", pch="*")
  lines(p_vec, asnWcurt, col="red",lty=2)
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but you should perhaps be resetting `summ_m <- 0` at the start of each `i` loop.

Comment: could you be more specific about your question, are you trying to optimize the function and information about the other variables are missing e.g which would n4_1 or n4_2 be?

Comment: Thanks for your responses I didn't realize there were responses to my question. I'm trying to formula this equation.

Comment: The equation that I am trying to translate to code is: ASN(p) <- n1 + summationOfI (n2xdbinom(i,n2,p) + summationOfM(m*npbinom(c2,m,p))*pbinom(i,n1,p) I hope that explains it more clearly